# Maximum number of SAN (subject alternative names) allowed

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509

Is there any limit for subject alternative names in X.509? Also are there any rules for the SAN?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "are there any rules for the SAN?"

Comment: @frasertweedale rules like, it should not contain domain different than CN, or wildcard should not be in SAN

Comment: Thanks; I have included information on these topics in my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**1. Also are there any rules for the SAN?**

[RFC5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) specifies Subject Alternative Names as

```
SubjectAltName ::= GeneralNames
```

whereby GeneralNames are

```
GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName
```

So, look the up the 'rules' for a `GeneralName` in the rfc (page 37).

**2. Is there any limit for subject alternative names in X.509?**

As stated in the same rfc in chapter *Appendix B.  ASN.1 Notes*:

```
The SIZE (1..MAX) construct constrains the sequence to have at least
one entry.  MAX indicates that the upper bound is unspecified
```

Comment: *MAX indicates that the upper bound is unspecified* - The sentence thereafter also is important: **Implementations are free to choose an upper bound that suits their
   environment**

Answer (score 8):

The Subject Alternative Name extension is fully specified by [RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6).

Some rules or notes about the use of this extension include:

- The subject name MAY be
  carried in the subject field and/or the subjectAltName extension.  Note that if any `dNSName` is present in the subjectAltName extension, then *all* DNS names should be included there, including those in the subject name field.  See [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) for details.
- If the only subject identity included in the certificate is
  an alternative name form (e.g., an electronic mail address), then the
  subject distinguished name MUST be empty (an empty sequence), and the
  subjectAltName extension MUST be present and marked as critical.
- Subject alternative names MAY be constrained in the same manner as
  subject distinguished names using the [name constraints extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10).  That is, the name constraints extension on a *CA certificate* can impose a name space within which all subject names (including alternative names) in
  subsequent certificates in a certification path MUST be located.
- If the subjectAltName extension is present, the sequence MUST contain
  at least one entry.  No upper bound is defined; implementations are free to choose an upper bound that suits their environment.
- Unlike the subject field, conforming CAs MUST
  NOT issue certificates with subjectAltNames containing empty
  GeneralName fields.
- The semantics of subject alternative names that include
  wildcard characters are
  not addressed by RFC 5280.  However, [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2) states "the wildcard character '*' SHOULD NOT be included in presented identifiers"